# Java/VSCode. Error Package Does Not Exist

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have the following directory structure. I'm trying to import .jar files downloaded from the Maven repository.

[image]

Unfortunately, I'm getting a "Package Does Not Exist Error" for databind and annotation. I want to compile the following code in the file Test.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Test {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      String json = "{\"id\" : 1}";
      Student student = mapper.readerFor(Student.class).readValue(json);
      System.out.println(student.getTheId());
   }
}
class Student {
   private int id;
   Student(){}
   Student(int id){
      this.id = id;
   }
   @JsonProperty("id")
   public int getTheId() {
      return id;
   }
   @JsonProperty("id")
   public void setTheId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
   }   
}
```

What's weird is that IntelliSense detects the package; however, when I compile Test.java the java compiler cannot find the packages within the .jar files.

Here is a copy of my settings.json:

```
{
    "java.project.sourcePaths": [
        ".",
        "lib\\jar"
    ],
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": {
        "include": [
            "lib/**/*.jar"
        ],
    }
}
```

The .jar files are in my Project library, and the ClassPath targets the folder containing the .jar files. Any idea what could be going on? Why would there be a disconnect between IntelliSense and the Java compiler?

Thanks!

Comment: What can you get if you run `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I deleted everything within windows and recreated the following directory structure:

[image]

My settings.json file:

```
{
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "lib/**/*.jar",
        "src/jar/jackson_annotations.jar",
        "src/jar/jackson_databind.jar",
        "src/jar/jackson-core-2.14.1.jar",
    ],
    "java.project.sourcePaths": [
        "src\\jar",
        "."
    ],
    "java.project.outputPath": "bin"
}
```

I can build and run this code. The Powershell run command that VSCode implements is:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\java.exe' '@C:\Users\LUKESL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_1u6y7pr0vey3xwzkph587nlcw.argfile' 'src.JacksonTester'
```

However, the issue comes when I delete the bin directory and click run (without pre-compiling). I get the following:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class src.JacksonTester
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src.JacksonTester
```

This is so weird. Does anybody know what's going on? I can still operate, but this behavior makes using VSCode awkward.

Thanks